# Best practice for manipulating Collections

Tags: java, collections

Following situation:
I've created some methods, that allow me to manipulate a List. For a simple example these methods are addSomeElements(...) and removeSomeElements(...)

What is the best approch to call those methods? I know following ways to do that, but don't know which one's the best?!

1) re-initialize the list

```
private void doSomething(List<String> list) {
   list = addSomeElements(list); 
   list = removeSomeElements(list);
}
```

In this case the methods would of course have to return a list:

```
private List<String> addSomeElements(List<String> list) {
    list.add(...);
    return list;
}
```

2) create new variables

```
private void doSomething(List<String> list) {
   final List<String> list2 = addSomeElements(list); 
   final List<String> list3 = removeSomeElements(list2);
}

private List<String> addSomeElements(List<String> list) {
    final List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(list);
    newList.add(...);
    return newList;
}
```

3) work with void methods

```
private void doSomething(List<String> list) {
   addSomeElements(list); 
   removeSomeElements(list);
}

private void addSomeElements(List<String> list) {
    list.add(...);
}
```

This would be the easiest way, but I don't really like it, because I think for the user it's not always obvious what you're doing. If you have an int for example, you would declare it like int myInt = 0. When you want to change the value, you could just say myInt = 1. It's clear that myInt has now a new value. But with the list it's different. The list you want to change might just be one of several parameters of the method you wanna call to modify the list. The user may probably not recognize that you've modified the list, which seemed to be only a Parameter, if the naming of the method doesn't tell it.

What would be the "cleanest" approach here?

Comment: Why do you need a wrapper around `List#add` ?

Comment: What's the point of returning the list to the caller, since the caller is the one that passed that list in the first place? It aready has a reference to the list. That would be useful if the method created a copy and returned the copy. But it doesn't. Returning the list will make every caller wonder why you return the list.

Comment: i'm going after gate number 3, as your method does not create new list, and operates with old one, i don't think there is any need for returning it. in fact, returning a new list might make fake impression you are using copy of the list

Comment: @JBNizet Ok, makes sense. But I thought of that solution, because I wanted to show the user, that the list has changed. When your working with void methods for example, then I think it's not always obvious that the list was modified.

Comment: When a method is named addSomeElements() and takes a List as argument, I find it obvious that the list will be modified. If there's still room for interpretation, that's what the javadoc is for.

Answer (score 2):

If you're modifying the list passed into your method, don't return the list reference (your option #1 <s>and option #2</s> *since edited*); it gives the impression at the API level that you're creating a *new* list, not modifying the one you were given.

That leaves you with two choices, either of which is "best practice" depending on context:

1. Modify the list passed in, and use `void` methods (or methods that return something else entirely if appropriate). (This is your option #3.)
2. Create new lists with the additions/removals, and return a reference to the new list. (This is *like* your edited option #2, but note that you would also have to return `list3` out of `doSomething` for it to make sense.)

Comment: Please mind that OP updated his question after your answer. So his suggestion "#2" is what you wrote as "2.".

Comment: @Tom: Thanks for letting me know; updated.

Comment: @Tom thats correct. I forgot to add this snippet, and did it afterwards.

Comment: @picobas That's ok, but you should also notify the users who already wrote an answer, so they can consider that.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating new lists instead of manipulating existing instances. Working with immutable state (which means copying state instead of modifying state) generally leads to cleaner code and less bugs. So I recommend going on the 2) way.

The mutable approach (modifying an existing list) may be faster, but don't go this way unless you have a very good reason to optimize.